# Масштабирование ImageView

Tags: java, android, android-imageview

Как можно реализовать `ImageView` c возможностью касаниями масштабировать изображения?(так же как в обычных фото галереях?)

Answer (score 2):

Есть несколько готовых решений. Например [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView)

Answer (score 0):

Есть отличная библиотека https://github.com/jsibbold/zoomage.
После подключение зависимости, добавляете как обычный ImageView в ваш XML. В ней картинку можно увеличить пальцами.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".fragments.MyPictureFragment">

    <com.jsibbold.zoomage.ZoomageView
        android:id="@+id/container_for_picture"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:zoomage_animateOnReset="true"
        app:zoomage_autoCenter="true"
        app:zoomage_autoResetMode="UNDER"
        app:zoomage_maxScale="8"
        app:zoomage_minScale="0.6"
        app:zoomage_restrictBounds="false"
        app:zoomage_translatable="true"
        app:zoomage_zoomable="true" />
```